# Unexpected height of width-constrained FlowLayout-Container

Tags: codenameone

Putting FlowLayout-Container into a width-constraining parent Container yields unexpected results.

What should be the expected result?

I'd expect the FlowLayout containers so fit their content.

Run this code and tap the Buttons:

```
public class FormFlowLayoutInTableLayout extends Form {
    public FormFlowLayoutInTableLayout() {
        setTitle("FormFlowLayoutInTableLayout");
        setScrollable(false);
        getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        Button buttonBorderLayout = new Button("BorderLayout");
        Button buttonTableLayout = new Button("TableLayout");
        Component containerSouth = Container.encloseIn(
                new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.X_AXIS), 
                buttonBorderLayout,
                buttonTableLayout);
        getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, containerSouth);
        Container containerCenter = new Container(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        containerCenter.setScrollableY(true);
        getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, containerCenter);
        ActionListener<?> actionListenerRefreshContainerUsingBorderLayout = (e) -> {
            containerCenter.removeAll();
            for (int tally = 0; tally < 10; tally++) {
                Component container = createRowContainerUsingBorderLayout();
                container.setUIID("ListRenderer");
                containerCenter.add(container);
            }
            containerCenter.revalidate();
        };
        ActionListener<?> actionListenerRefreshContainerUsingTableLayout = (e) -> {
            containerCenter.removeAll();
            for (int tally = 0; tally < 10; tally++) {
                Component container = createRowContainerUsingTableLayout();
                container.setUIID("ListRenderer");
                containerCenter.add(container);
            }
            containerCenter.revalidate();
        };
        buttonBorderLayout.addActionListener(actionListenerRefreshContainerUsingBorderLayout);
        buttonTableLayout.addActionListener(actionListenerRefreshContainerUsingTableLayout);
        Display.getInstance().callSerially(() -> actionListenerRefreshContainerUsingTableLayout.actionPerformed(null));
    }

    private Component createRowContainerUsingBorderLayout() {
        Container container = new Container(new BorderLayout());
        container.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, createSomeLargeFlowLayoutedContainer());
        Container containerRight = new Container(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        containerRight.add(createSomeSmallUpperLabel());
        containerRight.add(createSomeSmallLowerLabel());
        container.add(BorderLayout.EAST, containerRight);
        return container;
    }

    private Component createRowContainerUsingTableLayout() {
        TableLayout tableLayout = new TableLayout(2, 2);
        Container container = new Container(tableLayout);
        container.add(tableLayout.createConstraint(0, 0).verticalSpan(2).widthPercentage(60), createSomeLargeFlowLayoutedContainer());
        container.add(tableLayout.createConstraint(0, 1).horizontalAlign(Component.RIGHT), createSomeSmallUpperLabel());
        container.add(tableLayout.createConstraint(1, 1).horizontalAlign(Component.RIGHT), createSomeSmallLowerLabel());
        return container;
    }

    private Container createSomeLargeFlowLayoutedContainer() {
        return Container.encloseIn(
                new FlowLayout(), 
                new SpanLabel("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"), 
                new SpanLabel("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"));
    }

    private Label createSomeSmallUpperLabel() {
        return new Label("SmallUpper");
    }

    private Label createSomeSmallLowerLabel() {
        return new Label("SmallLower");
    }
}
```

Comment: A screenshot would help here.

Answer (score 0):

`FlowLayout` breaks lines which is one of the reasons why we recommend avoiding it especially with components that recalculate size e.g. `SpanLabel`, `TextArea` etc.

The challenges related to non-deterministic layout are discussed to some extent in https://www.codenameone.com/blog/the-challenge-of-multiline-strings.html

When you use flow layout we don't know how the final layout will look and that creates uncertainty which results in undesirable side effects.

Comment: When using Labels instead of SpanLabel it's even worse.

So what are You saying - the default Layout of Codename One is FlowLayout and this is not working?

Comment: A `new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS)`handles several FlowLayout containers well. Is it that BorderLayout and TableLayout have trouble handling contained FlowLayoutcontainers?

Comment: We don't reflow. That's a conceptual decision. Reflow requires recursion and creates a level of complexity in the layout code that makes it slow. That is the main reason why mobile web is slow https://www.codenameone.com/blog/why-mobile-web-is-slow.html